# MySQL Shutdown Unexpectedly and Fixed by Repairing mysql DB

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a very wierd issue after installing new OS and new XAMPP,
After restoring my old htdocs and mysql's DBs including the **ibdata1**, The mysql service always stopped with the known message **MySQL shutdown unexpectedly** when I'm trying to access any Database rather than the **mysql DB**,

BUT...

Once I open **mysql DB** and select all tables and **Repair Tables**, it worked perfectly and all Databases opened, and no more stops.

But after stopping mysql's service manually and restart it, I MUST open mysql's DB and repair all tables to be able to access DBs.

I've tried to **Empty session data** but nothing work except repairing mysql's DB tables.

Comment: You have fixed it already, so what is the question ?

Comment: What does `select version();` show? Is your backup data from a different version?

Comment: @RohitGupta 
I must repair mysql DB tables every time I start xampp

Comment: @ysth
I was working on xampp 2019 I can't remeber the version of course but now I'm using the xampp with php 7.4 not 8.1

Comment: what does the sql query `select version();` show?

Comment: Look in services to see if you have more than one copy of mysql running

Comment: @ysth 10.4.27-MariaDB

Comment: Try starting the database server and running the mariadb-upgrade command.  That does any updates needed to data files to be usable by a new version.